# How to render a component above another component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that renders only when a button in clicked but i want it to be above all other components but the component is rendering along with other components 
I kept the z index of above component
 higher(10)

Comment: What you are looking for is a modal: https://blog.bitsrc.io/build-a-simple-modal-component-with-react-16decdc111a6

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Please remember that we dont have any context to your question / application so you have to explain things in more detail. Here we dont know what `above` means. Is it just higher up in order of the elements? or on top? is it a modal? does it need to be relative to its parent container? Theres a lot of possibilities, we need you to help narrow down the types of answers you'll get by being more explicit in the question :)

Comment: i think modal or popup is what are you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have to give one example to you to understand the concept that how the render works. I hope this might help to clear your dought. In below example

```
return (
        <body className="page-landing">
            <PageTop>
                 <TopPlayers topPlayersData={this.props.topPlayersData} />
            </PageTop>
            <PageBottom>
                 <RecentGames recentGamesData=    {this.props.recentGamesData}/>
            </PageBottom>              
        </body>
       );
```

React will only render the top-level custom components PageTop and PageBottom, as you already found out. The other components (TopPlayers and RecentGames) are nested within those components. What does that mean? React does not just display those nested components because it would not know how to do this. Instead, all rendering must be done by the outer components PageTop and PageBottom. React just passes the nested components to them (PageTop gets TopPlayers, PageBottom gets RecentGames) in this.props.children. Now it is up to the outer components what to do with these nested components. In above example, you would modify the PageTop and PageBottom components to use {this.props.children} to display their nested components in a suitable way.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in css for that component, this will make it a modal.

```
{width: 400px; height:300px position:absolute; z-index:999; top: 50%; left:50%; margin-top: -150px; margin-left: -200px; overflow: auto;}
```